# Problema con la clase ZipArchive en php

Tags: php, linux, macos

Mi cuestión radica en que estoy comprimiendo más de dos archivos en formato **`.ZIP`** desde un servidor. Al hacer pruebas locales en **Windows** funciona sin problemas, al correrlo en sistemas **Linux** o **Mac** de manera local o incluso en servidor, se presenta un error al momento de descomprimir el archivo.

¿Qué debo tomar en consideración para hacer este tipo de cosas, es decir, codificaciones de los archivos a comprimir, usar el comando `exec` en lugar de la clase **`ZipArchive`** de **PHP**?

EDICIÓN:

Ya logré reparar el error. El problema era la adición de los archivos al .ZIP.... Dejaré el código que me funciona:

```
$folder = "ubicacion-archivos/";        
    if (extension_loaded('zip')&&$result) {
            //Se crea la clase Zip
            $zip = new ZipArchive();
            $nombreZip = "file.zip";
            //Se crea el archivo Zip
            if ($zip->open($nombreZip,ZIPARCHIVE::CREATE)!==TRUE)
                $error .= "Error con el zip";

            while ($objetoZip = mysqli_fetch_object($result))
                    $zip->addFile($folder.$objetoZip->archivo,$objetoZip->archivo);

            //Se agrega el archivo excel al Zip
            $zip->addFile('archivos-a-agregar');    
            //Se cierra el archivo Zip
            $zip->close();

            //Si el archivo zip se creó con exito
            if (file_exists($nombreZip)) {
                    header("Content-Type: application/zip");
                    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$nombreZip.'"');
                    header("Pragma: no-cache");
                    header("Expires: 0");
                    readfile($nombreZip);
                    //Se elimina el Zip del servidor
                    unlink($nombreZip);
            }
    }
```

Comment: ¿Cual es el error que recibes al intentar descomprimir el archivo? ¿Podrías incluir en tu pregunta un [un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? O el código que tengas desarrollado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debe existir la extensión ZipArchive, no todas las distros la traen por default:

En Linux usa (dependiendo de la distro):

```
sudo apt-get install php-zip
sudo yum install php-zip
```

para instalarlo y si no funciona busca el paquete con:

```
sudo apt-cache search php-zip
sudo yum search php-zip
```

No olvides reiniciar tu servidor Web, ya sea Nginx o Apache.

Comprueba la existencia de esta extensión usando la función `phpinfo();` en cualquier página o ejecuta `php -i|grep more` desde línea de comandos.